# Meaning of different phases in two-state system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, two-level-system

Assuming we have the state of some particle (maybe in this case an electron).
Is there an intuitive explanation what the difference between

$|\psi\rangle = a|0\rangle+b|1\rangle$ and $|\psi\rangle = a|0\rangle - b|1\rangle$

is. I mean there is no difference in the probability in observing one state or the other.
Im in my 6. Semester in Physics but i never really understood what the physical meaning of the phase difference in a two-state problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean there is no difference in the probability in observing one state or the other.

This is only true if you measure in the computational basis. If you measured it in a different basis, you could potentially distinguish the two states. In fact, it can be shown that if the two states are orthogonal, then they may be reliably distinguished with a single measurement.

The phase is very important in quantum mechanics. It's what makes QM not just a theory of classical probabilities. After all, if we could only measure in the computational basis, why bother with all this linear algebra nonsense? We could just specify the state of the system with a single real number, the probability of measuring 0, and it would admit a natural interpretation in terms of a probabilistic ensemble over an underlying state-space {0, 1}. The possibility of changing the phase, together with the possibility of measuring in different bases, makes QM different.

As for a physical interpretation, I suppose it depends what you mean by "intuitive". In the case of a two-level system, the Bloch sphere provides an "intuitive" picture for what's going on. It's especially apt if the two-level system is a spin-1/2, because then we can interpret each state as being a different direction the spin could point in. (To be more technical, if the two-state system supports a natural projective representation of the 3-dimensional rotation group, then it will rather naturally admit a geometric interpretation.)

Comment: I guess its hard to find anything intuitive about quantum states but I think I understood. If we take a spin-1/2 system we can measure not only in the z-direction (our computational basis) but also in the x-direction in which basis the phase is definately relevant. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help!